# Unable to install the perl module Net::SSH::Perl on windows 64 bit

Tags: perl, 64-bit

I have installed active perl on windows 2008 server (64 bit).
I tried installing Net::SSH::Perl using the command cpan install Net::SSH::Perl. After asking a few questions it started installing but failed stating that "make test had returned bad status, won't install without force. So  I tried with the command to force the installation, cpanp install Net::SSH::Perl. But still no success. Got the error ending "Unable to create a new Distribution object for 'Net::SSH:Perl' -- cannot continue"

Can someone help me install this module? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Net::SSH::Perl is old an unmaintained, use [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2) instead.

**update**: The Net::SSH2 distribution includes a file describing how to install it under Windows ([BUILDING.WIN32](https://metacpan.org/source/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.45/BUILDING.WIN32)).

Also, If you are using ActiveState Perl, you can get precompiled packages from here: http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/

Comment: I tried installing the  Net::SSH2 instead. not able to do that too :(

 -- cannot continue
[ERROR] [Fri Jul  6 05:45:10 2012] Unable to create a new distribution object for 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' -- cannot continue
[ERROR] [Fri Jul  6 05:45:10 2012] Failed to install 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' as prerequisite for 'Net::SSH2'
[ERROR] [Fri Jul  6 05:45:10 2012] Unable to satisfy 'configure_requires' for 'Net::SSH2' -- aborting install
[ERROR] [Fri Jul  6 05:45:10 2012] Unable to create a new distribution object for 'Net::SSH2' -- cannot continue