# return remote ssh version in perl using Net::SSH2

Tags: windows, perl, ssh

I need to get the remote sshd version using Net::SSH2  from a windows

```
   ./check_ssh -H exemple.com 
    OpenSSH_6.0p1  (Protocol 2.0)
```

In case the ssh is shutdown just display Connection refused or Socket Timeout if the connection is not specifically refused.

The end purpose would be to simulate the behavior of check_ssh nagios plugin from a windows box. I will be connecting from that windows box to an unix appliance and send the results of my script to nagios via nrpe.

I do not need to login.
I have been trying to install in dwim perl Net::SSH::Perl without success the only one I managed to install was Net::SSH2. I do not need support for ssh v1.

Comment: Please include the error you get while trying to install Net::SSH::Perl.

Comment: Net::SNMP::Perl is old and unmaintained
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329617/unable-to-install-the-perl-module-netsshperl-on-windows-64-bit)

same as this: that is already 2 years old without solution.
[link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1063317)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IO::Socket::INET` module.  For example:

```
$ cat ssh.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  PeerHost => 'localhost',
  PeerPort => 22,
);

$socket->print("\n");
my $output = join '', $socket->getlines();

print $output;
```

What the output would look like:

```
$ ./ssh.pl
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
Protocol mismatch
```

From this point you simply need to parse the output.

Comment: how to simulate the fact that the connection times out? or when connection is refused. i get this instead:
   can't call method print on an undefined value at check_ssh.pl line 44

Comment: Simulate? Do you mean handle?  Take a look at the IO::Socket::INET documentation, there's a timeout parameter you can set.  http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the netcat utility you could use that to check it.  For example:

```
 my $NC = `nc -w 1 localhost 22`;
 print $NC;
```

In this example netcat connects to localhost on port 22 and times out after 1 second.

Comment: netcat for windows.. get flagged as virus by my company antivirus..I would prefer if possible use snmp modules.

Comment: What about cygwin?  It's possible to install netcat with that.

Comment: This is a company server. perl and its modules is the maximum I can install and they made an exception because it is the only gateway to the network where the server I need to check is. I rather use Perl modules only.